# elasticsearch multi_match with regexp

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to rebuild my elastic search query, because I found that I don't receiving all documents I am looking for.

So, let's assume that I have document like this:

```
{
  "id": 1234,
  "mail_id": 5,
  "sender": "john smith",
  "email": "johnsmith@gmail.com",
  "subject": "somesubject",
  "txt": "abcdefgh\r\n",
  "html": "<div dir=\"ltr\">abcdefgh</div>\r\n",
  "date": "2017-07-020 10:00:00"
}
```

I have few millions documents like this and now I am trying to search for some by query like this:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": "100%",
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "query": "abcdefgh johnsmith john smith",
            "operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "email.full",
              "sender",
              "subject",
              "txt",
              "html"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": [
              "1234"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "mail_id": 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For query like this it is all fine, but when i want to find document by query 'gmail' or 'com', it would not work.

```
"query": "abcdefgh johnsmith john smith gmail"
"query": "abcdefgh johnsmith john smith com"
```

It will work only when I will search for 'gmail.com'
    "query": "abcdefgh johnsmith john smith gmail.com"

So... I was trying to attach analyzer

```
...
"type": "cross_fields",
"query": "abcdefgh johnsmith john smith",
"operator": "and",
"analyzer": "simple",
...
```

Does not help at all. The only way I am able to find this document was define regex, e.g.:

```
"minimum_should_match": 1,
"should": [
  {
    "multi_match": {
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "query": "fdsfs wukamil kam wuj gmail.com",
      "operator": "and",
      "fields": [
        "email.full",
        "sender",
        "subject",
        "txt",
        "html"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "regexp": {
      "email.full": ".*gmail.*"
    }
  }
],
```

but in this approach I will have to add (queries * fields) regexp objects to my json, so I don't think it will be the best solution. I also know about wildcard but it will be mess just like with regexps.

If anyone had problem like this and know the solution I will be thankful for help :)

Comment: Can you show what your mapping for the `email` field is inside ES?

Comment: email.full is just {"type" : "text"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your search term through the standard analyser you can see what tokens `johnsmith@gmail.com` gets broken down to. You can do this directly in your browser using the below URL:

```
https://<your_site>:<es_port>/_analyze/?analyzer=standard&text=johnsmith@gmail.com
```

This will show that the email gets broken down into the following tokens:

```
{

    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "johnsmith",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "gmail.com",
            "start_offset": 10,
            "end_offset": 19,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        }
    ]

}
```

So this shows that you can't search using just `gmail` but you can using `gmail.com`. To split your text on the dot too you can update your mapping to use the [Simple Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) which says:

> The simple analyzer breaks text into terms whenever it encounters a character which is not a letter. All terms are lower cased.

We can show this works by updating our URL from earlier to use the simple analyser as below:

```
https://<your_site>:<es_port>/_analyze/?analyzer=simple&text=johnsmith@gmail.com
```

Which returns:

```
{

    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "johnsmith",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "gmail",
            "start_offset": 10,
            "end_offset": 15,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "com",
            "start_offset": 16,
            "end_offset": 19,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 3
        }
    ]

}
```

This analyser may not be the right tool for the job as it ignores any non-letter values but you can play with analysers and tokenisers until you get what you need.